# How can i solve a Jenkins error with docker-compose

Tags: jenkins, docker-compose, continuous-integration, devops, continuous-deployment

Im trying to run jenkins with docker-compose

```
version: '3.5'
services:
  jenkins:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./jenkins.Dockerfile
    volumes:
    - $PWD/jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home
    - $PWD:/app
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

but in the end appears this access denied error when it try to access to some volumes. I cannot open Localhost in my browser.

```
WARNING: The Docker Engine you're using is running in swarm mode.

Compose does not use swarm mode to deploy services to multiple nodes in a swarm. All containers will be scheduled on the current node.

To deploy your application across the swarm, use `docker stack deploy`.

Starting 8fd02292a7fe_ejercicio_jenkins_1 ... 
Starting 8fd02292a7fe_ejercicio_jenkins_1 ... done
Attaching to 8fd02292a7fe_ejercicio_jenkins_1
8fd02292a7fe_ejercicio_jenkins_1 | Can not write to /var/jenkins_home/copy_reference_file.log. Wrong volume permissions?
8fd02292a7fe_ejercicio_jenkins_1 | touch: cannot touch '/var/jenkins_home/copy_reference_file.log': Permission denied
8fd02292a7fe_ejercicio_jenkins_1 exited with code 1
```

how can i solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

run

```
chmod 777 -R $PWD/jenkins_home
```

Comment: This doesn't include a warning about what it will do and the security implications, it doesn't indicate where to use it (command line, or inserting into the docker-compose as part of exec), what to expect when it is run, how it will work, why it works, etc.